React Recharts drawing ReferenceLine at the top of the chart
Chart Screenshot
i'm trying to draw a reference line at this AreaChart for threshold values, which is the Y value of the chart.
And the domain of the Y value is the cumulative amount of data traffic (100KB, 112GB, 12PB etc)
If there is a threshold for the traffic, i want to draw a ReferenceLine for that threshold, so the user would be able to notice the traffic is about to exceed or has exceeded the limitation.
    <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height='100%'>
        <AreaChart data={cumulativeData} margin={{ top: 20, right: 5, left: 10 }}>
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='3 3' />
          <XAxis dataKey='startedAt' />
          <YAxis
            width={70}
            padding={{ top: 30 }}
            tickFormatter={byteFormatter}
          />
          <Tooltip
            formatter={(value) => [
              `${byteFormatter(value as number)} (${commaizeNumber(value as number)} bytes)`,
              t('metrics::dataType.edgeTransfer')
            ]}
          />
          {thresholdList?.items.map((threshold) => (
            <React.Fragment key={threshold.toId().id}>
              <defs>
                <linearGradient id='splitColor' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='1'>
                  <stop offset={offset} stopColor={theme.palette.error.main} stopOpacity={0.32} />
                  <stop offset={offset} stopColor='white' stopOpacity={0} />
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <ReferenceLine
                y={threshold.transfer.threshold}
                ifOverflow={'visible'}
                orientation={'right'}
                stroke={theme.palette.error.main}
                label={<ReferenceLabel value={byteFormatter(threshold.transfer.threshold)} />}
                strokeDasharray='5 3'
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
          <Area
            dataKey='edgeTransfer'
            fill={`url(#splitColor)`}
            connectNulls

this is my code for that.
in the screenshot, the chart's y range is 0 ~ 111.76 GB.
If the y prop for ReferenceLine (threshold) exceed far more than the range of the chart (like, 10 TB.), i want to draw ReferenceLine at the top of the chart.
Recharts provide ifOverflow prop for that, but i don't want to 'extendDomain' cause as the chart is extended to 10 TB, it gets so hard to see the graph for the cumulative data.
  <YAxis
    width={70}
    padding={{ top: 30 }}
    tickFormatter={byteFormatter}
    // domain={['auto, 'auto']} <- default props value

  />

THE Y VALUE OF THE TOP POSITION is calculated by the library, by the domain prop of the domain, and padding.
is there anyway that i can get THAT VALUE??
